# parsing a log file and extract powershell

Tags: powershell, variables, logfile

i have this in a log file, and i want only the time without (s) in a new log file or put in variable, thanks for your reponse.

```
Fri Nov 02 13:47:07 2018  time =5.803s
Fri Nov 02 14:02:10 2018  time =7.082s
```

My Code

```
Get-Content "logfile.txt" |
    select-string -pattern "5" |
    foreach-object{
        write-Output $_ >> "C:\Users\titi\Desktop\test.txt"
    }
```

Comment: What have you come up with so far? Show us your code and we'll be happy to help you to make it work.

Comment: my code is Get-Content "logfile.txt" |  select-string   -pattern "5" | foreach-object{ write-Output $_ >> "C:\Users\titi\Desktop\test.txt"}, i know that take only line with 5 but i want to take line superior at 5

Comment: Just guessing with superior line you mean the following line - take a look at he `-context` parameter of Select-String. You should [edit] your question to contain the exact output you expect.

Answer (score 1):

this will get the info you seem to want ... [*grin*]

```
# fake reading in a text file
#    in real life, use Get-Content
$InStuff = @'
Fri Nov 02 13:47:07 2018 time =5.000s
Fri Nov 02 13:47:07 2018 time =5.803s
Fri Nov 02 14:02:10 2018 time =7.082s
Fri Nov 02 13:47:07 2018 time =4.000s
Fri Nov 02 13:47:07 2018 time =3.000s
Fri Nov 02 13:47:07 2018 time =5.001s
'@ -split [environment]::NewLine

$MinimumSeconds = 5.0

$Results = foreach ($IS_Item in $InStuff)
    {
    $Seconds = [decimal]($IS_Item.Split('=')[1].Trim().TrimEnd('s'))
    if ($Seconds -gt $MinimumSeconds)
        {
        $Seconds
        }
    }

''
$Results
```

output ...

```
5.803
7.082
5.001
```

what happened above ...

- split on the '='
- take the 2nd part of the resulting array
- trim away any leading or trailing whitespace
- trim away the ending 's'
- convert to a `[decimal]` value
- compare to the required minimum
- send the remaining number to the `$Results` collection
- display it

saving it back to a file would use Set-Content. [*grin*]

Comment: if i have 4.000s that can display but i want superior at 5

Comment: @jack - what do you mean by "superior at 5"? i have no idea what that means ... please, try to rephrase it.

Comment: if i have this value :                                                                                                            Fri Nov 02 13:47:07 2018 time =5.803s
Fri Nov 02 13:47:07 2018 time =4.000s
Fri Nov 02 14:02:10 2018 time =7.082s                                                                                                     i want only a value superior at 5.000s so i want 5.803 and 7.083, thanks

Comment: @jack - ah! so you want the values _greater than_ 5.0 ... i will post a way to do that in my original answer in a while. [*grin*]

Comment: @jack - take a look at the current version - i added a "coerce from string to number" & then a comparison to the required minimum.